# Gradle throwing exceptions in debugMode. Exception in thread "main" java.net.UnknownHostException:

Tags: java, flutter

Exception in thread "main" java.util.zip.ZipException: zip END header not found
at

> 

```
java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$Source.zerror(ZipFile.java:1581)
    at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$Source.findEND(ZipFile.java:1476)
    at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$Source.initCEN(ZipFile.java:1483)
    at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$Source.<init>(ZipFile.java:1288)
    at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$Source.get(ZipFile.java:1251)
    at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$CleanableResource.<init>(ZipFile.java:732)
    at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$CleanableResource.get(ZipFile.java:849)
    at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:247)
    at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:177)
    at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:191)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.unzip(Install.java:214)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.access$600(Install.java:27)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:74)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:48)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.ExclusiveFileAccessManager.access(ExclusiveFileAccessManager.java:65)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.createDist(Install.java:48)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:128)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:61)
```

Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

Exited (sigterm)

Comment: What is the name of your computer has as a top level name e.g. in a network it may be called LXZworkSt31 whereas in these type of downloads in your OS settings configuration you usually need to be called **localhost** as the computer name.
See also the config file for the downloads.

Comment: I'm using a Linux (Pop OS) running on an intel inside processor with 1.6ghz speed and a 4GB RAM.
Because of the RAM and processor, I usually run my flutter apps in debug mode on a physical android device

Comment: It's just a point with calling online repositories that the connection config in the local java code of the downloader needs to identify the host machine calling and a bug in having default configuration of the net connection requires the name localhost. In Linux you go to your general general computer settings in root mode change the computer name to localhost , if such a problem in windows you go into its settings and name the computer localhost.